# Load Image of different resolution into opengl es 2.0 android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I am working on a android application built using opengl es 2.0. I have to load a image to Opengl as texture. The texture works fine if the image is of size 512x512. But If i change the resolution to something like 1200x850 the image does not appear. I need to have a option where users can select there texture from any image file in there phone. So I need to support all image sizes.

Comment: Check that your device supports bigger textures than 1024 pixels. Use glGetInteger with GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mārtiņš suggested, check your maximum texture size, but also a lot of OpenGL implementations require texture dimensions to be a power of 2.  You can resize the user's image to an appropriate value (like 1024 x 512).